# string to integer in scientific notation

Tags: julia, scientific-notation

What is the canonical way of converting a string storing a number in scientific notation into an integer?

#### from

```
"1e6"
```

#### to

```
1000000
```

---

As for the reverse process, converting integer to string in scientific notation I understand I can use `@sprintf` macro. If one knows the exact format to achieve exactly the reverse process - so small `e` and no extra trailing `.00` zeros (like `1.00e6`), or leading zeros (like `1e08`) - I will appreciate if it will be included for completeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion from string to integer can be achieved via floats like this:

```
julia> Int(parse(Float64, "1e6"))
1000000
```

if you know that the number will fit into `Int64` or like this

```
julia> BigInt(parse(BigFloat, "1e6"))
1000000
```

for larger numbers.

For the reverse process the default in `@sprintf` would be the following:

```
julia> @sprintf("%.0e", 1_000_000)
"1e+06"
```

However, you get `+` after `e` and at least two digits are displayed in the exponent (both features are a standard to expect across different languages when you do such a conversion). Also note that this process will lead to rounding, e.g.:

```
julia> @sprintf("%.0e", 1_000_001)
"1e+06"
```

Comment: `+0` I will deal with using `replace` function then. Thanks

Comment: I thought of recommending it, probably the correct regex to use is e.g. `replace("1e+01", r"[+]0?"=>"")`.